# É deselegante trocar a resposta por outra resposta?

Tags: debate

Um cara me enviou uma solução, mas com muito código escrito. Antes dele um outro me enviou e estava legal, acontece que naquela hora eu não consegui fazer funcionar, e a outra funcionou de prima. Acontece que agora a primeira resposta funcionou e eu estou usando-a, pois consegui fazer rodar. A pergunta é: Após ter marcado uma resposta, é errado ou deselegante "virar a casaca" e optar pela outra? Só uma pergunta e não sei se faria isso.

Comment: Não é, todavia é bom que você tenha em mente que só porque um código funciona não quer dizer que ele é bom ou que ele é correto, ou que ele não causará problemas futuros. Portanto no momento de escolher a resposta que melhor resolveu o seu problema estude o código e tenha certeza que aquilo será bom para você e para outros usuários que tiverem problemas semelhantes. Então pra resumir, o principal é que a resposta nova seja boa mesmo, tem muitas respostas que são apenas um punhado de código de código sem uma explicação descente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, concordo. Fui precipitado em responder, mas no momento precisava do resultado. Hoje limpando os códigos, tentei pela outra resposta e consegui o resultado com bem menos linhas, bem menos mesmo. Mas vou deixar assim.